# Can I deliberately block/cancel/ban my account for a month?

Tags: support, feature-request, banned

As a curiosity, can I block or disable my own account, for say a month?

You can imagine ...

(a) one is busy writing a novel or something, and you want to 'prevent the distraction to yourself' (just as an alcoholic may, um, lock up the bottles)

(b) perhaps, an employer might insist a young employee stops spending so much time, say

Is this possible? I've often been blocked for a month on SO sites for swearing, etc -- is it possible to "time out" yourself, say for a month?

Cheers

PS for the sake of searching/tags, what is it called when a user is blocked/banned?

---

I appreciate the humour etc, does anyone actually know if this can be done?

I mean technically, is it possible?  Where is the button?

Actually, come to think of it, if I have enough points, can I simply ban myself?

Cheers...

Comment: I'd much rather you worked on the ole *self-discipline* a bit. You've made lots of useful contributions to the site over the time you've been here, and more would be welcome. I don't know if *intoxicants* are a factor in you getting worked up and consequently banned, but if so you could always consider sticking to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) whenever you've got a drink or a joint in hand (I've done that a few times myself over the years! :)

Comment: Hey Fumb!  lol you may not understand what I'm saying just here...  for sure on the self-discipline.  I just mean I want the account **self-blocked** purely because I am **busy with work** and I don't want the time temptation. For example, I just now deleted RailTycoon from all the computers ("OMG").  And I deleted Kindle from some devices. (What with the next episode of *I am number four* coming out .. gotta resist.)  So that's the point here...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My thought exactly. +1. When did it become SE's job to be the user's nanny?

Comment: @Robusto: It's not, obviously. But [this recent contribution](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/190071/2637) from Joe is far from atypical. It's cogently-argued, accurate, and shows greater-than-usual diligence in researching supporting evidence (Plus it's one of the few contributions on that page supporting *my* position, but in theory that's irrelevant! :) All I'm really saying is it would be nice if Joe could find *some* way to get his relationship with ELU sorted, since IMHO he's often a valuable contributor with useful insights, knowledge, and the will/means to present arguments well.

Comment: hi @Robusto. Your comment is odd.  It is no different if I asked "say, how do I change my avatar image?" or "How do I set a new password?" or whatever. It's just a technical question.  No biggie.

Answer (score 7):

Change your password to a long string of letters, numbers, and symbols that you could not possibly memorize. Write it down on a piece of paper and seal it in an envelope. Deliver the envelope to a trusted friend, and ask them to hold onto it for a month. Inform them that under no circumstances are they to return the envelope to you before the month is up.

To be extra cautious, change your registered email address to that of your trusted friend, so you can't request a password change in a moment of weakness.

To be extra extra cautious, edit the hosts files on all of your computers to redirect any requests for english.stackexchange.com to 127.0.0.1, so you can't visit and use the site as an unregistered user in a moment of weakness.

To be extra extra extra cautious, create a user account with limited privileges on your computer to use for the duration. Change the password for your root or administrator account and put it in the envelope for your trusted friend, so you can't repair your hosts file in a moment of weakness.

To be extra extra extra extra cautious, arrange to be put into a medically induced coma for a month, so you won't be tempted to find workarounds for the above listed precautions in a moment of weakness.

Comment: I'm sure climbing Everest or training for a manned Mars mission or joining up for the next BioDome would equally suffice if OP were concerned about the physiological effects of inducing a coma.

Comment: ... mail it to a safety deposit box that is then dropped in the middle of the ocean. Then forget how to type because you can always create a new email address and SE account.

Comment: @Mitch: Oh, ye of little faith! I have complete confidence they *will* find the Flight MH370 black boxes eventually. Also that eventually Joe will be recognised as such an important person that similar resources will one day be directed to finding that safety deposit box. That box will by then be revered as a *holy relic* (much more important than the Turin Shroud, which has long been recognised as just a fake! :).

Comment: PH - I realised there's a germ of a good idea in your joke answer. I guess, one could change the email address to perhaps an employee or something, and ask that person to please not revert the account for a month!

Comment: @Joe: A few years ago I tried without success to find a cheap/free automated way of being able to send myself emails for future delivery. I thought it was as obviously useful as setting your alarm to wake you up at some future time (usually, tomorrow morning), so I was quite surprised when I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Fumb - that's actually an astonishingly good idea.  I can't believe, there is no such service online!

Comment: What about https://www.followupthen.com .. memotome.com .. http://web.appstorm.net/roundups/task-management/creating-automated-reminders/